# New ArrayList for each Object

Tags: java, class, arraylist, foreach

I'm trying to make an auction system and I've got two classes called `Bid` and `Auction`. I want to create an `ArrayList` for each Auction object, so I can easily keep track on each bid for an auction. I considered using a for-each loop, but not sure whether it works and if so, how to even do it properly. As far as I've tried the ArrayList is just overwriting itself.

Anyone that could provide me with some help? Thanks.

Comment: This is very vague. Can you show us some code that highlights your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Auction {

    private String description;

    List<Bid> bids = new ArrayList<Bid>();

    public void addBid(Bid bid) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.bids)) {
            bids = new ArrayList<Bid>();
        }
        bids.add(bid);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Bid> getBids() {
        return bids;
    }

    public void setBids(List<Bid> bids) {
        this.bids = bids;
    }
}

class Bid {
    private String userName;

    private double price;
}
```